# How to add static fields to one constructor value?

Tags: java

I want to sort cards but don't know how to connect the different card types with the actual variable int type using the constructor.

"Set the types of cards as final static fields in class Card, so that they can be called via for example Card.EFFECT_MONSTER."

No enum allowed.

```
public class Card{
    public String name;
    public int releaseDate;
    public int type;

    final static int EFFECT_MONSTER = 1;
    final static int NORMAL_MONSTER = 2;
    final static int SPELL = 3;
    final static int TRAP = 4;

    public Card(String name,int type, int releaseDate){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: "How can i connect the four different static fields with the int type?" what do you mean by that statement?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do and what "connect the four different static fields with the int type" is supposed to mean. Please consider adding some code to your question to better describe what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: 1) why those varables are static 2) what does this statement "How can i connect the four different static fields with the int type?" mean ?

Comment: A very important point which you seem to be lacking (based on your question) is this: constructor is used to *instantiate* the class, i.e. create an object of it; static members do not belong to instances, they belong to classes. While you can reassign values to static members, it's not really recommended to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand your code, then what you are trying to do is best achieved by using an [Enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) data type. Enumerations allow you to define a number of predefined constants that you can then use as a data type.

So you should define an enum for the card type:

```
public enum CardType {
    EFFECT_MONSTER,
    NORMAL_MONSTER,
    SPELL,
    TRAP;
}
```

And then inside your card class use that enum as the type:

```
public class Card {
    public String name;
    public int releaseDate;
    public CardType type;


    public Card(String name, CardType type, int releaseDate){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

}
```

creating a card would then work like

```
 new Card("SpellCard", CardType.SPELL, 0);
```

**For the non-enum solution:**

There is no way to somehow "automatically connect" your single int to the 4 static variables and if you aren't allowed to use enums then doing more complex solutions like using a Collection and/or java reflection is probably out of the question to. So your only way in that case is to really do everything manually.

For example in the constructor you could do:

```
public Card(String name,int type, int releaseDate){
    this.name = name;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    
    boolean isTypeEffectMonster = (Card.EFFECT_MONSTER == type);
    boolean isTypeNormalMonster = (Card.NORMAL_MONSTER == type);
    boolean isTypeSpell = (Card.SPELL == type);
    boolean isTypeTrap = (Card.TRAP == type);

    if (!isTypeEffectMonster && !isTypeNormalMonster && !isTypeSpell && !isTypeTrap) {
        // invalid type passed into constructor
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Type: " + type);
    } else {
        this.type = type;
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: i don't know about enums yet, is there a more beginner way?

Comment: enums are a very basic java functionality. Honestly I would consider the way you are trying to do it (defining static variables and then manually checking if the passed int matches one of them) to be less beginner-friendly than just using an enum.

Comment: it looks pretty easy with enums but i'm not allowed to use them because we did not cover the topic yet

Comment: @user17687046 I added an example for a non-enum solution. But the short answer is that yes, you would have to check those 4 values manually everytime you handle this value. Are you allowed to use Collections like Lists/Sets? I'm just assuming when you aren't allowed to use enums then Collections aren't allowed either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "connet the four different static fields with the type int" , hope this is what you are asking.

```
class Card {
   public String name;
    public int releaseDate;
    public int type;

    final static int EFFECT_MONSTER = 1;
    final static int NORMAL_MONSTER = 2;
    final static int SPELL = 3;
    final static int TRAP = 4;

    public Card(String name,int type, int releaseDate){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;

        // Accessing the static variables, this is how you can access the static variable inside constructor. I've demoed a simple logic , don't know what you are trying to achieve
        this.releaseDate = Card.NORMAL_MONSTER;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getReleaseDate(){
        return this.releaseDate;
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't understand how i can access the four different static fields. Do i have to type every single one in the constructor or can i somehow connect them to the int type, so i can access them via type?